# How parse a link by text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have content:

```html
<p><a href="/dms_pubrec/itu-t/rec/q/T-REC-Q.1238.3-200006-I!!TOC-TXT-E.txt" target="_blank"><strong><font size="1">Table of Contents </font></strong></a></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="80%">   </td>
<td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFF80" style="font-size: 9pt;">
<p><a href="./htmldoc.asp?doc=t\rec\q\T-REC-Q.1238.3-200006-I!!SUM-TXT-E.txt" target="_blank"><strong><font size="1">Summary </font></strong></a></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="font-size: 9pt;color: red;">
<p>This Recommendation includes an electronic attachment containing the ASN.1 definitions for the IN CS-3 SCF-SRF interface</p>
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to extract:

- text from following href  and
- link, where following text Summary

```html
<a href="./htmldoc.asp?doc=t\rec\q\T-REC-Q.1238.3-200006-I!!SUM-TXT-E.txt" target="_blank"><strong><font size="1">Summary </font></strong></a>
```

My code:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Q.1238.3-200006-I/en"

q = requests.get(url)
result = q.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pull the url which is associated with the text `Summary` :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Q.1238.3-200006-I/en"

q = requests.get(url)
result = q.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')

link= soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Summary")').get('href')

print('https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Q.1238.3-200006-I'+link)
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Q.1238.3-200006-I./htmldoc.asp?doc=t\rec\q\T-REC-Q.1238.3-200006-I!!SUM-TXT-E.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the content and `href` links in an `<a>` tag you can loop over the content with `find_all` as follows:

```python
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    return a.contents, a['href']
```